# insert a space after a specific character with awk?

Tags: awk

How do I insert a space after a specific character with awk?

The test data

`<>jhjashdhasdkh`

I want to insert a space " " after > so the data string would become...

The modifyed test data now becomes...

`<> jhjashdhasdkh`

Does anyone know how to do that with awk. ? I've tried everything I can..

Thank you for helping,

Comment: You are wanting to insert a space after an occurrence of '>'? Your test data string doesn't even contain an '>'. There are plenty of examples of how to do this out there, or just ask one of your classmates who's already figured it out.

Comment: Dude, that was not helpfull, why did you respond. you are saying that "<>jhjashdhasdkh" doesnot contain a >" Your crazy. I'm asking for help because I need it. I dont have time to figure it out. Thats what help is all about.

Comment: Well the lt and gt signs are there now, thanks to jonsca for editing your post. Sorry ArealPerson, this just reaks of homework.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to read about the `sub` and `gsub` functions in the [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to insert a decimal point after a number. 
`NewBid = substr(spotBidRate,1,1) "." substr(spotBidRate, 2)`

The sample input: spotBidRate=367305000 
 The Sample output: NewBid=3.67305000 
 
So in your case, it would be a space, 
 `NewBid = substr(spotBidRate,1,1) " " substr(spotBidRate, 2)` 
 
 Hope that helps!